# SQL: Select dynamic column name based on variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Microsoft SQL stored procedure whose column name I want to set via a variable that is passed into it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [My_Procedure]
   @myDynamicColumn varchar(50)
AS BEGIN
   SELECT 'value' AS @myDynamicColumn
END
```

This does not work ("Incorrect syntax").  If I wrap the column name with [ ]:

```
SELECT 'value' AS [@myDynamicColumn]
```

The column name literally outputs as '@myDynamicColumn' instead of the actual value.  Is there any way to do this? I've looked into dynamic SQL articles but nothing is quite what I'm asking for.

Comment: Why? This isn't how SQL should be used

Comment: @gbn: right on.  
@dotNewkow: Im sure this is just a contrived example to illustrate your issue, but gbn is correct: this is complex because its wrong.  If you need to alias a return from the stored procedure then just do the aliasing in the calling code, where you obviously already know the value of @myDynamicColumn.   If you post more details about your problem perhaps we can offer more than dynamic sql.

Comment: Good question.  Yes, I understand the dangers of dynamic SQL.  @Nathan Skerl, you're correct, normally you'd want to set this via the calling code.  However, I'm running this query as a data connection in Excel for reporting purposes.  The Client wants 4 reports with relatively the same data but with different column names, so I made a stored proc for reusability & to follow the DRY principle. If this was a view, I could do: "SELECT [column] AS [My Dynamic column name] FROM [My View]" but since it's a stored proc I can only do "EXEC My_Procedure 'My Column Name'".

Comment: DRY would be to alias this in the client and keep the SQL contract identical. It isn't a SQL problem. DRY would also mean using the same name anyway. Having 4 names for one attribute is confusing...

Comment: How about changing the procedure to take in @ReportId and then within procedure emulate what you would do in view... ie, IF @ReportId = 1 then select 'value' as [MyDynamicColumn] else if @ReportId = 2 ...

At least you dont have to take on the baggage of dynamic sql. For a small number of reports/column headers I would go this route.

Comment: @Nathan Skerl: Thanks, I like this approach.  Much better.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
EXEC ('SELECT ''value'' AS ' + @myDynamicColumn)
```

Comment: Thanks, you answered 45 seconds after the other guy, so have an upvote!

Comment: @dotNetkow: Actually, I was 9 seconds ahead of "the other guy", 15:49:30 vs. 15:49:39.

Comment: Always a bridesmaid, never a bride.

Answer (score 22):

You could build your query into a string and use exec

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [My_Procedure]
   @myDynamicColumn varchar(50)
AS BEGIN
   EXEC('SELECT ''value'' AS ' + @myDynamicColumn)
END
```

Answer (score 6):

Both the upvoted answers are **very** dangerous here, both are wide open to injection attacks and should **not** be used.

When injecting dynamic object names you *must* ensure you properly quote your object names. SQL Server has a built in function for that, `QUOTENAME`. Thus what you should actually be doing is the following:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [My_Procedure] @myDynamicColumn sysname
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT ''value'' AS ' + QUOTENAME(@myDynamicColumn) + N';';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
END
```

You'll note I also change the data type of the parameter to `sysname`, a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`, which is the data type SQL Server uses internally for object names.

Comment: Hello 10 years in the future! You are correct, this is a creative solution to a problem I had long ago. It's in a different comment but: The query was ran as a data connection in Excel for reporting purposes. The Client wanted 4 reports with relatively the same data but with different column names, so I made a stored proc for reusability & to follow the DRY principle. Only ever ran internally, and the sprocs stripped from Excel before passed over to the client. cheers!