# Dynamically choose column in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database field name call `Code` and I am trying to select it using a variable name like this below:

```
Declare @var1 = [Code]

(SELECT @var1
 FROM [VoucherType]
 WHERE [DeletedBy] IS NULL
 AND [AutoID] = 1)
```

Apparently, SQL will interpret `@var1` as a string and not the field of my database, how can I do it in such a way `@var1` is recognized as the field name `[Code]` instead of a string possibly without any select or if statements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(255)

SET @var1 = 'Code'
SET @sql = 'select ' + QUOTENAME(@var1) + ' from [VoucherType] where [DeletedBy] is null and [AutoID] = 1'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

You'll have to compose a dynamic query, and execute using `sp_executesql`

To add more on the 'dynamic' side of things, use stored procedures. See here for an example:

http://www.marten-online.com/database/execute-dynamic-sql-in-mssql.html

That is... if you are using Microsoft SQL SERVER

Comment: `+ @var1 +` should be `+ QUOTENAME(@var1) +` to avoid problems with spaces and other possible special characters in column names. It also helps prevent possible injection issues. Also, If you're composing a comma separated list each individual column name should be passed through QUOTENAME.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use Dynamic SQL.

```
declare @ColName varchar(128)

declare @sql varchar(4000)

Set @ColName='Code';

select @sql = 'SELECT '+@ColName+'
  FROM [VoucherType]
 WHERE [DeletedBy] IS NULL
 AND [AutoID] = 1'
  exec sp_executesql @sql
go
```

This post might be helpful

[Accessing a table from a name in a variable](http://www.mindsdoor.net/SQLTsql/TableNameAsVariable.html)

[SQL: Select dynamic column name based on variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637983/sql-select-dynamic-column-name-based-on-variable)

Regards

Comment: `EXEC` should be avoided in favor of `sp_executesql` because it is more efficient: [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a variable like that in a SELECT statement.

You will need to create dynamic TSQL.

You don't specify your RDBMS, but in SQL Server you would use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) (preferably) or `EXEC`

```
Declare @var1 varchar(100)
Declare @sql varchar(1000)

SET @var1 = '[Code]' 
SET @sql = ' select ' + @var1 + ' from [VoucherType]' +
           ' where [DeletedBy] is null and [AutoID] = 1'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Be sure to read: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50)

SET @var1 = '[Code]'

EXEC ('SELECT ' + @var1 + ' FROM [VoucherType]  
       WHERE [DeletedBy] IS NULL AND [AutoID] = 1 ')
```

Comment: `EXEC` should be avoided in favor of `sp_executesql` because it is more efficient: [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx)