# How to select one field value, along with the field's type and size?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to read **one field** from table "*bfEvent*" along with the associated *Column Name*, *Data Type*, and *Max Length* of said field.  The field name will not be known (is passed in) and can be any datatype.

Below is what I'm trying to do, although of course it does not work.

Any ideas?

-- VARS...

declare @Field   varchar(50)

declare @EventID int

-- VALUES PASSED INTO STORED PROC...

set @Field   = 'Deadline'

set @EventID = 16

```
-- WHAT THE PROC SHOULD DO...
   select isc.Column_Name
        , isc.Data_Type
        , isc.Character_Maximum_Length
        , isc.Ordinal_Position
        , evt.@Field as Value        ***here is the problem***
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc
   where isc.Table_Name = 'bfEvent'
     and isc.Column_Name = @Field
     and isc.Column_Name = evt.@Field  ***and here***
     and evt.EventID = @EventID
```

The table bfEvent looks like:

```
EventID   int
EventName varchar(50)
EventDate datetime
Deadline  datetime
SomeText  text
BoolFld   bit
```

Comment: Have you seen [this SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8454706/772086)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to receive the data from table, you need to point to table. You trying to query the metadata table. There you can receive the needed metadata, but not the data.

In both scenarios it's prefer to get the info beforehand and link to the result set.

The below query will perform the needed:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'select metadata.*, data.Value
from
(
    select Value = ' + @Field + ' from bfEvent where EventID = @id
) data,
(
    select
      isc.Column_Name
    , isc.Data_Type
    , isc.Character_Maximum_Length
    , isc.Ordinal_Position
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc
    where table_name =''bfEvent''
    and column_name = ''' + @Field + '''
) metadata
';
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@ID int', @ID = @EventID;
```

The result will be in the following format:

```
Column_Name Data_Type   Character_Maximum_Length    Ordinal_Position    Value
```

Additional info about dynamic SQL queries can be found here:

- [MSDN - EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [MSDN - sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.100).aspx)