# Selecting data using varyng source column

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am wondering if there is a way to select "like".
For example i have columns h1, h2, h3 i want my select to pick which column to grab based on user input.

```
Select like "user var will be 1,2 or 3" from table
```

Can you have a varying select or will i have to do 
`Select * from table` and then filter my data table?

Another though I had was through having it add the h onto the users var in C#

`Select 'h" + var + " ' from table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the query on the fly:

```
int col = Convert.ToInt32(request["usercolumn"]);
string q = "SELECT h" + col + " FROM table";
```

My c# is a bit weak, but the gist here is take the user input, make sure it's an integer and build your query using the user input.

Comment: This is what i waslooking to do i had ' ' around it and it was failing lol, so i was looking for otherways, took the extra ' ' off and works great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * is typically bad practice.  If you did something like the data table filtering I would specify the possible columns explicitly.  I would also look at using dynamic SQL. [Dynamically choose column in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454671/dynamically-choose-column-in-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Robbert code will work but if use will enter greater than 3 then that will give error, better to use case like this

```
DECLARE @col int  = 1
select case @col when 1 then h1
                 When 2 then h2
                 Else h3 END
From table
```