# SQL: SELECT statement with column names taken from different table (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an in-line function called `myfunc` and it returns a `TABLE`.

I can select certain columns from the function like so:

```
SELECT col1, col2, coln FROM myfunc()
```

However, is it possible to dynamically change the SELECT columns based upon a different table?  We can assume the other table has all available column names (no typos, etc.)

Something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT available_cols FROM <other_table>) FROM myfunc()  --pseudo code
```

It looks like this can be achieved using the [`EXEC` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454671/dynamically-choose-column-in-sql-query) but I'm curious if this can be baked into the SELECT command from the get-go.

Thank you.

Comment: You definitely need dynamic sql to do something like this.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't give you many opportunities to mix *metadata* and *data* together in a single query. Trying to do so usually means that the data model has become mixed up about the separation between those concepts.