# Select in select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a `table(validation_number)` that contains an **unique id and comma separated name** of columns:
[Table is in similar fashion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFLU9.png)

The column name are the column names of another table(**Validation** )which I want to show or hide based on the validation number.

I've tried select (select columns from table where validation number=3) from validation, but it has not provided the desired result.

I have also tried storing the result of this query in a variable and calling it in the other query but this also has not worked. Please help.

Comment: Choosing what columns to display or not is a choice for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer. Also, storing delimited data in your database is a very poor choice; normalise your design.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically choose column in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454671/dynamically-choose-column-in-sql-query)