# How can I create a month name as a column name for a given date range in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data as below:

Table

---

```
country     date                value       
------------------------------------------------------
test1       5/1/2008            500
test1       5/7/2008            200 
test1       5/8/2008            300
test1       7/1/2008            100
test1       7/2/2008            100
test2       6/1/2008            100
```

And I want a result as below:

```
 Result
-----------
countryName          May-08         Jun-08      July-08
test1                1000             -          200
test2                 -              100
```

Comment: What is your database SQL Server, MySQL or Oracle, tag it

Comment: you could use pivot function

Comment: but in pivot i have to give a fixed column right?

Comment: It might be complex query. Please select all records and maintain it programming way rather then SQL query...

Comment: you could create put all the dynamic columns in a variable, and then make it as statement, and then EXEC your query

Comment: How can i created dynamic column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is adapted from [T-SQL Pivot? Possibility of creating table columns from row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922797/t-sql-pivot-possibility-of-creating-table-columns-from-row-values)

You can see it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b8c0/28

I think you might need to fiddle around with the column ordering

```
-- Static PIVOT
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT country,
      CONVERT(char(3), date, 0) + '-' +  
      RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(date)), 2) AS date,
      value
FROM country) AS D
PIVOT(SUM(value) FOR date IN([May-08],[Jun-08],[Jul-08])) AS P;
GO

-- Dynamic PIVOT
DECLARE @T AS TABLE(y INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

DECLARE 
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@y    AS INT,
@sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(char(3), date, 0) + '-' +  
      RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(date)), 2) AS y 
      FROM Country
     ) AS Y
ORDER BY y desc
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'')

-- Construct the full T-SQL statement
-- and execute dynamically
SET @sql = N'SELECT *
FROM (SELECT country, CONVERT(char(3), date, 0) + ''-'' +  
      RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(date)), 2) AS date, value
FROM Country) AS D
PIVOT(SUM(value) FOR date IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P;'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: what is the meaning of 'FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'')'?

Comment: It's just a neat trick to concatenate the column names into a string. There's an article here: http://www.mahipalreddy.com/blog/?p=79

Comment: one more question can we create a month name as in given a date reange ex if i given a date 5/1/2008 to 7/2/2008 then how can i create a month may,june and july month as column name? as like we create above

Comment: i mean if i not insert a last record of " 6/1/2008" this into table then after i should show output "test1  1000      -        200" like this,it is possible?

Comment: can i add a date range in (SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(char(3), date, 0) + '-' +  
      RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(date)), 2) AS y 
      FROM Country
     ) AS Y
in this query or any else i have to add a date range can u tell me pls? becoz my date range is not a fixed so column also not fixed

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a rather complex query for that, using a `LOOP` it think.

For creating dynamic column names look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10926106/1321564

With sql server you have some advantages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5638042/1321564