# giving alias name of the substitution variable

Tags: sql, linux, shell

Is there a way for an alias to have a name associated with the string name passed?

i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as $1 
FROM TABLE orders...
```

The reason I want something like this is because I am calling this SELECT statement 40 times and am passing different variable values each time.
So, I would like for this SELECT statement to display the name of the parameter passed with an actual COUNT.

My script calls counting.sql:

```
@/D2RQ/counting.sql 'Parameter' 'CLIENT'
@/D2RQ/counting.sql 'Line' 'CLIENT'
@/D2RQ/counting.sql 'Setting' 'CLIENT'
@/D2RQ/counting.sql 'Protocol' 'CLIENT'
.
.
.
```

Here is my counting.sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total_Number_of_Triples
FROM TABLE(SEM_MATCH(
'{
        ?s rdf:type :&1 .
        ?s ?p ?o
}',SEM_Models('&2'),NULL,
SEM_ALIASES(SEM_ALIAS('','http://DataSource/SEMANTIC#')),NULL));
```

Alex solved it:

```
define MY_ALIAS = &1
define MY_MODEL = &2

SELECT COUNT(*) as &MY_ALIAS
FROM TABLE(SEM_MATCH(
'{
        ?s rdf:type :ProcessSpec .
        ?s ?p ?o
}',SEM_Models('&MY_MODEL'),NULL,
SEM_ALIASES(SEM_ALIAS('','http://VISION/DataSource/SEMANTIC_CACHE#')),NULL));
```

This works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637983/sql-select-dynamic-column-name-based-on-variable

Comment: 40 times? Did you tried to select all with only 1 query?

Comment: Are you using SQL in PHP? Just asking since you have a $, but then again PHP variables must start with a letter or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the variable as a literal to echo it back out in the result:

```
SELECT '$1', COUNT(*) as count
FROM TABLE orders...
```

This won't affect the calculation of `count(*)`