# Select column names from one table based off of values in column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

This could be a repost; if so, link me and I will delete.

First off, I am a SQL newb. I have two tables, table_1 and table_2. I want to select the column names from table_1 that only correspond to values found in a column named 'foo' from table 2.

How can I got about this? Does this require an inner join?

I have some code I can post, but it is a disaster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637983/sql-select-dynamic-column-name-based-on-variable

Comment: I am not sure that post answers my question. Could you elaborate on why this post could help?

Comment: I updated my answer please check it. After you satisfied my answer can you give tick mark and up vote please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is one type of example.

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.col1= table2.col2
```

we follow these above syntax.

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.col1= table2.foo
```

These is the how find out column_name is present in another table

```
SELECT * FROM(    SELECT letter  FROM `Table_2` ) a JOIN
(SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database_name' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='Table_1') b ON a.letter= b. COLUMN_NAME
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is joining the two tables based on common values found in columns. I am wanting to join based on column names of table_1 and values found in column foo in table_2. Am I way off track here? Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: I am referencing the column names in table_1 by select "column_name" FROM "information_schema"."columns" 
WHERE "table_name" = 'table_1'

Comment: you don't know what columns in table_1 to compare in table_2  correct?

Comment: No, I do not want to select any columns from table_1. I want to select the names of the columns in table_1 (not their values).

Comment: You want only empty columns in table1 ?

Comment: No, not empty columns. The information I want to select is all of the column identifiers from table_1 which are found in the foo column of table_2.

Comment: Table_1 has columns "A" "B" "C" "D". Table_2 has column "letter: Column "letter" has values 'A' 'B' 'C'. The columns 'A' 'B' 'C' match up to the values in column 'letter'. How can I design a query which does this?

Comment: Ok, i understood now give me few minutes. I will update my answer. Thanks for providing valuable information.